# Make order list refresh in each 5 minute in magento admin

Tags: magento2, php, orders, javascript, sales-order

Is this possible in magento admin to make order list refresh if system is idle for 5 minute ??? my client want to make order list refresh in each 5 minute because he don't want to make page refresh whole page. he want automatically refresh the order list refresh on new order from there store .i try to fit here but here its not working can anyone can helpout

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
 setTimeout(function(){
 window.location.reload(1);
 }, 5000)
```